# Use Angular 7 *ngFor item out of scope in the same DOM?

Tags: angular, scope

Let's assume I have this code:

```
<div id="first-div">
  <div id="second-div">
    <div id="third-div">
      <a *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{ item }}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is how could I possibly use the "item" variable out of all the divs?

Something like this:

```
... use of item

<div id="first-div">
...
</div>
```

Comment: One every iteration, the `item` will be the current index object. So simply moving the `ngFor` before your `first-div` should be fine. Even with hacks like setting refrence, etc. The reference will always point to either the last object or current index during iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`No`** you cannot use it outside the ngFor item outside it's scope.

You can either move the ngFor outside the dive or copy it to new variable and use it

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. The scope of the `item` variable is the `*ngFor`.